# ubuntu 13.10 armhf and amd64 lib uuid-dev installation

Tags: ubuntu

I am trying to install two versions of the lib `uuid-dev:amd64` and `uuid-dev:armhf`.
My system is set up to accept armhf libs because:

- I added the architecture `dpkg --add-architecture armhf`
- I edited my `sources.list` to have the repo for the armhf libs, for example `deb [arch=armhf] http://ports.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-ports saucy main restricted
- I updated everything `apt-get update`

But when I install `uuid-dev:armhf`, `uuid-dev` gets deinstalled and vice versa.
I know that I am missing something, but I don't know what...

Comment: By the way probably you would have more chances to get good answer on [Ubuntu-specific](http://askubuntu.com/) Stack Exchange site.

Comment: Hi, I tried, nobody responded. Shall I delete the question ?

Comment: No, leave it. It is computer-related question, so it is appropriate here.

Comment: I don't understand why you would need to install an ARM package on a x86_64 system…

Answer (score 0):

You can't install two different architecture applications at the same time. At the end the system has to deal with one of them so you must specify which application you want to use.

Comment: Yes you can, that is why `multiarch` is here. https://wiki.debian.org/Multiarch/HOWTO